# Where can I defined my style so that i can get in all Tabbed Page?

Tags: xamarin

I'm doing with my xamarin app.

And i want to style all of the same things (eg fontsize) like css in html by using class.

where can i actually put my code in?

Comment: Global Styles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application or via CSS at the Application : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/#xaml

Answer (score 1):

If you define it in `App.xaml` it will affect every page. If you leave `x:Key` empty then it will affect every control.